# Kinect 2 streams get stuck after fetching 3 frames

Tags: c#, image, kinect

I am using Kinect v2 and have a small program that only shows body and color streams but the stream stops sending frames after fetching just 3 frames. Here is the code:

```
_sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

        if (_sensor != null)
        {
            _sensor.Open();

            _reader = _sensor.OpenMultiSourceFrameReader(FrameSourceTypes.Color | FrameSourceTypes.Depth | FrameSourceTypes.Infrared | FrameSourceTypes.Body);
            _reader.MultiSourceFrameArrived += Reader_MultiSourceFrameArrived;
        }
```

and here is how I am getting frames

```
Console.WriteLine("==== FRAME FOUND ====");
        var reference = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame();
        // Body
        using (var frame = reference.ColorFrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (frame != null)
            {
                //stream.Children.Clear();
                var c_frame = reference.ColorFrameReference.AcquireFrame();
                ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
                Image im = new Image();
                rgb.Source = frame.ToBitmap();
                var b_frame = reference.BodyFrameReference.AcquireFrame();
                _bodies = new Body[b_frame.BodyFrameSource.BodyCount];
                b_frame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(_bodies);
                if (_bodies[0].IsTracked)
                {
                    stream.DrawSkeleton(_bodies[0]);
                    if (recording)
                    {
                        recorder.RecordFrame(_bodies[0]);
                    }
                }
                b_frame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(_bodies);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your build target is set to 32 bit CPU. Set it to 64 bit.